# How do I bind a variable on the parent to the selected value in an ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following code below. When I select a radio button from house.Rooms I want to set that value to house.SelectedRoom.  I know that ng-repeat has a child scope and I've tried everything from $parent.SelectedRoom to $parent.house.SelectedRoom but it doesn't seem to be setting the property on the parent object. `{{house.SelectedRoom}}` and `{{house.SelectedRoom.Name}}` aren't being set.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-repeat="house in town">
        <span>SelectedRoom = {{house.SelectedRoom.Name}} </span> 
        <div ng-repeat="room in house.Rooms">
            <input type="radio" name="$parent.$index" ng-model="house.SelectedRoom" /> {{room.Name}}
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your relevant js look like?

Comment: `(function () {

    angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('mainController', ["$scope", "$http",
            function ($scope, $http) {

                $http.get('/Test/GetData').then(function (response) {

                    $scope.town = angular.fromJson(angular.copy(response.data));
                });
            }]);
})();`

i dont know what its not formatting properly

Answer (score 0):

With the expectation that your javascript is functioning, you need to set the value of the radio button with the `value` attribute. You have specified where to put the `value` (`house.SelectedRoom`) but not what value is to be put there.

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
      <div ng-repeat="house in town">
          <span>SelectedRoom = {{house.SelectedRoom}} </span> 
          <div ng-repeat="room in house.Rooms">
              <input type="radio" name="room.Name" value={{room.Name}} ng-model="house.SelectedRoom"/> {{room.Name}}
          </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This angular code works when using a json structure like this for `$scope.town`:

```
$scope.town = [
  {
    Rooms: 
      [
        {
          Name: "Living Room"
        },
        {
          Name: "Kitchen"
        }
      ],
    SelectedRoom: ""
  }
];
```

Comment: this isn't working for me. it also has all the radio butttons with the same name. Here is my data return from the call to the server.

SelectedRoom is a room object

Comment: `[{"Rooms":[{"Name":"Kitchen","WallColor":"Blue"},{"Name":"Living Room","WallColor":"White"}],"SelectedRoom":null},{"Rooms":[{"Name":"Kitchen","WallColor":"Blue"},{"Name":"Living Room","WallColor":"White"},{"Name":"Garage","WallColor":"White"}],"SelectedRoom":null},{"Rooms":[{"Name":"Kitchen","WallColor":"Blue"},{"Name":"Living Room","WallColor":"White"}],"SelectedRoom":null}]`

Comment: What version of angular are you using? Check the script at https://jsfiddle.net/8svc0tup/2/

Comment: Also maybe try separating the app and controller in two separate `div`s.

Comment: I'm using angularJS version 1.5.5 to coincide with the version my company is using for this particular development project

Comment: i just tried separating the app and controller in two separate `div`s. there's no difference and im still having the problem

Answer (score 0):

got it working. had to use `ng-value` to bind an object to the radio button's value

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <div ng-repeat="house in town">
            <span>SelectedRoom = {{house.SelectedRoom.Name}} </span>
            <div ng-repeat="room in house.Rooms">
                <input type="radio" name="$parent.$index" ng-value="room" ng-model="house.SelectedRoom" /> {{room.Name}}
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```